# How do I run a function if List.FindIndex returns null Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game with an inventory system and the main inventory and the tool bar are separate game objects. when the inventory is full it doesn't know to start adding new items to the tool bar, and returns null because it cant find an empty slot. I'm trying to run a function that tells the game to add any new items to the tool bar if it can when the find index function returns null but am unaware of how this could be done. I need to know how to run a function when List.FindIndex returns null.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: it isn't necessary I'm just asking how do I check if List.FindIndex returns null `UpdateSlot(uiItems.FindIndex(i => i.item == null), item);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FindIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex) **never** returns `null`. If it doesn't find any item it returns `-1`.

So you could simply check for

```
var index = uiItems.FindIndex(i => i.item == null);
if(index > -1)
{
    UpdateSlot(index, item); 
}
else
{
    Debug.LogWarning("All slots full!");
}
```

---

Or instead of going by the index you could rather check if there is any free slot and use [Linq `FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault)

```
using System.Linq;

...

var freeSlot = uiItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.item == null); 
if(freeSlot != null)
{
    UpdateSlot(freeSlot, item);
    // Or if you still rather want to go by index
    //UpdateSlot(uiItems.IndexOf(freeSlot), item);
}
else
{
    Debug.LogWarning("All slots full!");
}
```

and of course accordingly make your method signature

```
void UpdateSlot(Slot, Item)
```

instead